# Google Meet integration api (like Hangouts app for Slack)

Tags: google-api, slack, google-hangouts, google-meet

## I want to utilise Google Meet api, which is used in Hangouts integration for Slack, description follows

#### TL;DR:

Links such as `https://meet.google.com/new?gid=123&gd=qwe987` can be generated, so a modal is shown which can ask user's confirmation and then some request is sent from user's browser (where the Google Meet page is opened) to some endpoint (probably it is determined from `gid` which seems to be `google application id`). Is there a way to configure my application to have a webhook, so I can generate these custom links?

---

There's [Google+ Hangouts app for Slack](https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS351-google-hangouts). Here's how it works (after you add the app in your workspace):

- you send `/hangout` command in any Slack channel
- slackbot sends an "Only visible to you" message in this channel with a link to start a new hangout. it looks smth like this (I changed data in the link): `https://meet.google.com/new?gid=691521906844&gd=THTJ30X6W%7CU01113BD13M%7CD01113BDB5Z%7Csuren%7C%7C1846381238693%7C1%7CB01QFGG5GJF%7CE1MDm4DWcuVa0RbN5ZT9o5KF`
- when you visit the link, a new meeting is started instantly, and the page shows modal with text "To bring others into this video call, post a link it to your Slack channel" with buttons 'Cancel' and 'Post'.
- when you click 'Post', a new message is sent to the Slack channel, where the command was sent. Text is "@Suren Khorenyan has started a Google+ Hangout and would like you to join. Join Hangout." and contains a link to the meet, which was created previously

**How can I utilise this integration for another app, like Mattermost (or anything else like Telegram chats via bots)?**

As I see, data in the url slightly changes. Probably it's payload for Google Meet to trigger Slack to send a message with link to the channel.

- `gid` seems to be something like *google app id*
- `gd` seems to be something like *google data*. If I url-decode it, it becomes `THTJ30X6W|U01113BD13M|D01113BDB5Z|suren||1846381238693|1|B01QFGG5GJF|E1MDm4DWcuVa0RbN5ZT9o5KF`. This is some kind of payload, separated by pipes (obviously), but I don't know what any part of this means (`suren` is my username in the Slack workspace, probably this is used for creating an invitation message).

When I click `Post`, this happens:

- a new `POST` request to `https://hooks.slack.com/services/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` is sent with form-data

```
hangout_id: 1812381238693
hangout_url: https://meet.google.com//abc-iuqx-def
```

- a new message is posted to the Slack channel

Google meet somehow knows where to post back! Is this configured at the Google application (application id is provided via `gid`)? How can I configure my application for such behaviour? **Where can I setup webhook url?**

If we breakdown the request, we can see that url contains some parts of the `gd` payload:

- `THTJ27X6W` - this is the first part of the `gd` payload
- `B01ABCD5GJF` - last but one
- `E1MDm4DWcuVa0RbK5ZT9o5KD` - the last part of the `gd` payload

and form-data contains:

- `hangout_id` - this is in the `gd` payload after my name
- `hangout_url` - obviously, this is the url for the new created meeting

#### How can I change it for my needs?

---

I created a new application at Google APIs dashboard (here `console.developers.google.com/apis`), but can't find **any** docs for this integration. There's `Google+ Hangouts API`  in `API Library`, but it says `Apps will continue to function until April 25, 2017.`.

**I tried to approach it from another side:**

In the `API Library` there's Google Calendar. I found `mattermost-hangout` app on GitHub (had to [update it a bit](https://github.com/chitter99/mattermost-hangout/pull/7), so it works with updated api). Here's how it works:

- oauth2 for authorising at google (single account)
- it handles `POST` request, which is meant to be received from Mattermost (triggered by a slash command),

  - creates a new calendar event using Google Calendar API (with conference),
  - takes hangouts url from the response and sends a new message in the Mattermost channel with invitation to join the meeting.

But it has some downsides:

- you have to use one account to authorise all event creation events (yeah, it can be upgraded to authorise any number of users, but it'll be inconvenient. why to force anyone to provide access to their Google Account, when Google Meet authorisation just happens in browser, we don't need to create events)
- account, used for auth, now has events in his calendar. of course, events can be deleted, but it's not *the way*.

### Is there any documentation on utilising `gid` and `gd` params?

Generally, I want to find a way to configure a webhook in my app, so when Google Meet finds my application's ID in the `gid` query param, it looks at the app's config and sends a request to my app (previously configured endpoint (I assume it works this way)).

Of course there's a chance that it's some kind of internal API and it cannot be used by everyone, but I could not find **any** information on this.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? it's crazy how there are no documentations at all?

Comment: @AliSalti nope, could not find a solution :(

Comment: FWIW on my Mac I've never managed to get the Google Meet that is started to show the dialog that allows me to post the link back to Slack.  Despite LOTS of attempts to debug this!